# Im using Thuderbird IMAP accesing my Gmail account, what folder needs to subscribe and what safe to unsubscribe?

Tags: thunderbird, gmail, imap

Im using Thuderbird IMAP accesing my Gmail account, what folder needs to subscribe and what safe to unsubscribe?

I ask this because I noticed that the messages inside say example: Important Folder, Starred Folder, etc, have the same contents meaning they are also have copies in either Sent Items and/or Inbox. How to resolve this? If I unsubscribe to all the folder but except Inbox and Sent Items only, will I be missing something on my messages?

Thanks you

Answer (score 1):

You are okay with unsubscribing from All, Important, and Starred. That is how I have my Thunderbird set up. It seemed redundant to download and cache messages twice when they are already stored in the Inbox.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So what else is okay to 'unsubscribed?' I also have many labels I have created on the web-version of Gmail, (example: Personal emails, School emails, Work email, Friends emails, etc). Is it also okay unsubscribing to those? Im not so familiar how that works?

Comment: It is safe to unsubscribe from those if you want. If you don't have a huge amount, I think it's nice to have those folders presorted for you. If you have many emails, it is duplicate emails that take up disk space.